# 'The version of QBXML that was requested is not supported or is unknown.' QuickBook

Tags: c#, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

When I try to connect to QuickBook 2013 us enterprise edition in order to pull the data. it throughs error 'The version of QBXML that was requested is not supported or is unknown.'
I am using QBFC13 even when I updated it to QBFC 14 it throws the same error.
`QBConnection.country = "US";

```
        QBConnection.requestMsgSet = sm.CreateMsgSetRequest(QBConnection.country, (short)13, (short)0);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to find out what the maximum version of qbXML your QuickBooks supports is?

Usually, QuickBooks releases are 1 ahead of the qbXML version they support. e.g. QuickBooks `2013` would likely support qbXML version `12.0`.